# How to Approve a Pull Request on AWS CodeCommit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pull-request, aws-codecommit

I'm new to AWS CodeCommit. I'm trying to figure out how to approve a Pull Request on AWS CodeCommit. I know how to create and manage Approval Rules. I know how to approve a PR using CLI. But I couldn't figure out how a user can login to AWS console and Approve a PR. I searched the internet but couldn't the answer. No AWS docs available on this.

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 4):

I got the issue. It was because of the user who created the PR will not be able to approve the PR even though he has permissions. Secondly, the user who will be approving the PR should be given respective approval permissions i.e. `Action: UpdatePullRequestStatus` in IAM policy. Only then the user will be able to see the approval button.